# Customize controller name translation in grails

Tags: grails, groovy

By default `SomeController.groovy` has a controller name of `some`. Also, `pkg.SomeController` has a controller name of `pkg/some`.

Is there a way to plug a custom mechanism for this translation. In my particular instance I want to get rid of the `pkg` (it's a long story why I need this)

I can try to use `@Controller("name")` but given the number of existing controllers this is less preferable.

Answer (score 0):

I was wondering if there's a customized URL mapping defined in your Grails project (look at `grails-app/conf/*UrlMappings.groovy`)? As far as I understand, the package name shouldn't show up in the URL by default.

Comment: yes, I have a custom mapping. I don't mean the URL part. I mean when the controller is referenced by name - for example in filter definitions, or in `<g:createLink`

Comment: I browsed the source of createLink and it seems it uses the defined URL mapping as well. However, there's also an optional mapping parameter to explicitly reference a named URL mapping. Maybe this helps...